# Problems with application state changes in iOS5

Tags: iphone, state, background-process

When compiling in iOS5, I'm experiencing some strange behavior in transition between states.

According to Apple documentation, when you push power (idle) button, the app must transit to inactive state, and stay in this state until the phone is unlock. In this state the app is running but not processing events. My app needs that.

But in iOS5 my app goes to inactive for a brief time (milliseconds) and then goes to background state, triggering applicationDidEnterBackground and leaving 10 minutes for terminate all activity. Exactly as you push the Home button.

I've found any documentation explaining this behavior change in the web or Apple developer portal.

My question is: ¿is somebody experiencing this problem? ¿Perhaps it's a bug in iOS5.0?